# How does it know what's next in this linked list?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, append

I understand most of the code, but what I don't understand is what's happening in the append_after function. How exactly are the elements in the linked list being appended after each other?
As far as I can see last_node.next is never being instructed to point to the next element. Also it says "While last_node.next is not None" but isn't it None by default? I'm not seeing what would make it not "None" if I didn't specifically code it to do that.

```
class node:
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class linked_list:
    
    def __init__(self):

        self.head = None

    def display(self):
        
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node.data)
            node = node.next
    
    def append_after(self, data):
        
        new_node = node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
    
        last_node = self.head # I'm assuming this starts at the letter "A"?
        while last_node.next is not None: # What makes it not None?
            last_node = last_node.next
        last_node.next = new_node # It comes here after finishing the loop?

ll = linked_list()

ll.append_after("A")
ll.append_after("B")
ll.append_after("C")
ll.append_after("D")
ll.display()
```

OUTPUT

```
A
B
C
D
```

Below is a different way to call the objects. If I call the objects like I do in the example below I can easily understand it because I can clearly see what's being defined as the next element, but I don't understand how the append_after function returns the same result.

```
ll = linked_list()

ll.head = node("A")
data2 = node("B")
data3 = node("C")
data4 = node("D")

ll.head.next = data2
data2.next = data3
data3.next = data4
ll.display()
```

I'm using Python 3 and I've already looked at similar questions but they weren't explained very well. Is something happening under the hood that I don't understand?

Comment: Please clarify what you don’t understand about this. You already identified where the next node is assigned, so how are you confused that it can have a value other than the default? Are you aware that the head is always the same even on subsequent calls? Did you inspect the state of the list at the various steps?

Comment: I thought i clarified everything pretty well but what i dont understand is how the code in the append_after function is appending the next node. It says "While append_after.next is None" but at what point is it "None"? And when you say the head is always the same, are you saying that for each time the different objects are called the head would still be the first element? in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to visualise the process. When `ll = linked_list()` is executed, an instance of `linked_list` is created, its `head` attribute is set to `None` and the reference to that instance is assigned to `ll`. We can picture the state as follows:

```
 ll
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: None │
└────────────┘
```

Now `ll.append_after("A")` is called. During this call `self` has the reference to the linked list, and with `new_node = node("A")` the new node is created with its `data` attribute set to "A" and its `next` attribute set to `None`. Let's already picture that state:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: None │
└────────────┘

    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │
    │ next: None │
    └────────────┘
      ↑
     new_node
```

Because `self.head` is `None`, we get into the `if` block, where `self.head = new_node` is executed. This makes the new node instance a member of the list:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         ▼
    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │
    │ next: None │
    └────────────┘
      ↑
     new_node
```

The `append_after` function returns, and the main program makes the call `ll.append_after("B")`. Again a new node is created with `new_node = node("B")`. This leads to this state:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         ▼
    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │    │ data: "B"  │
    │ next: None │    │ next: None │
    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                        ↑
                       new_node
```

This time the `if` condition (`self.head is None`) is not true, so we get to `last_node = self.head`, introducing another name that references the first node in the list:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         ▼
    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │    │ data: "B"  │
    │ next: None │    │ next: None │
    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
      ↑                 ↑
     last_node         new_node
```

Now the `while` loop starts, but its condition is false, because `last_node.next` is `None` -- which is an indication that it currently is the *last* node in the list. And that's what we need: we want to have a reference to the *last* node in the list so we can attach the new node just after it.

*After* the `while` loop (which didn't make iterations) we execute `last_node.next = new_node`. This performs the attachment:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         ▼
    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │    │ data: "B"  │
    │ next: ────────► │ next: None │
    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
      ↑                 ↑
     last_node         new_node
```

The function returns. Let's do one more call: `ll.append_after("C")`. Again a new node is created, the `if` condition is False, and `last_node` gets again a reference to the first node in the list. So just before the `while` loop starts we have this state:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         ▼
    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │    │ data: "B"  │    │ data: "C"  │
    │ next: ────────► │ next: None │    │ next: None │
    └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
      ↑                                   ↑
     last_node                           new_node
```

This time the `while` condition is true, which means that `last_node` is not what its name suggest -- it is *not* the last node in the list, so an iteration of the loop is executed, with `last_node = last_node.next`:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         ▼
    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │    │ data: "B"  │    │ data: "C"  │
    │ next: ────────► │ next: None │    │ next: None │
    └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                        ↑                 ↑
                       last_node         new_node
```

Now the `while` condition is true, which means that `last_node` is truly the last node of the list. It is here that we need to attach the new node. So after `last_node.next = new_node` is executed, we get:

```
 self (ll)
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ head: ─┐   │
└────────│───┘
         ▼
    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
    │ data: "A"  │    │ data: "B"  │    │ data: "C"  │
    │ next: ────────► │ next: ────────► │ next: None │
    └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                        ↑                 ↑
                       last_node         new_node
```

The call `ll.append_after("D")` will go through the same process: `last_node` will start again from the left, and via the loop it will reach the last node in the list, and then the new node will be appended there.

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining this. I think I understand now. 
First "A" is made, and it calls "B".
Then it skips the loop at first cause it's false and A.next becomes the new node "B".
Then it calls "C" and B.next makes the loop true so last_node becomes B and B.next becomes "C" and then it repeats for D.

I really appreciate it. I was trying to figure this out for days and i finally understand it inside and out. I would give you a thumbs up but since I'm new it wont let me.

Comment: I'm glad to see it helped you. Just a note on terminology: *"and it calls B"*: nodes are not "called". This is a term used for invoking functions. Nodes are *referenced*.